# Moving object declaration outside of function causes crashes

Tags: android, function, object, crash

This codes works:

```
public void saveRoutine() {
    datasource = new RoutinesDataSource(this);
    datasource.open();
    EditText routineName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.routine_add_name);
    String routineString = routineName.getText().toString();

    if (routineString.length() == 0) {
        Toast toast_routine_name_empty = Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.toast_routine_name_empty), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast_routine_name_empty.show();            
    }
    else {
        datasource.createRoutine(routineString);
        Toast toast_added = Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.toast_routine_added), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast_added.show();
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

However, when I move the line `EditText routineName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.routine_add_name);` ABOVE (outside) the `saveRoutine()` function, it causes my app to crash.

How do I make it so I can use the object inside of more than just the `saveRoutine()` function?

For example, I want to use the code below the `saveRoutine()` function to make it so when the ENTER key is pressed, it calls `saveRoutine()`:

```
routineName.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                    saveRoutine();
                    return true;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because if you put `EditText routineName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.routine_add_name);` above your method, that whole statement will then be global, and `findViewById()` will execute **before** `setContentView()`.

This will result in a null variable (there is no layout, so there won't be a View to assign to `routineName`) which then results in a `NullPointerException`. Your best bet is to make `routineName` global, so do just

```
EditText routineName;
```

outside the `saveRoutine()` method. For readibility and proper practise, declare it at the top of your class declaration before all methods.

Then do

```
routineName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.routine_add_name);
```

right after `setContentView()` in your Activity's `onCreate()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Put:

```
EditText routineName;
```

Outside your methods as a global variable and put:

```
routineName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.routine_add_name);
```

in or in any method after your `onCreate()` function (or after you have called `setContentView()` basically).

`setContentView()` looks for a view in the currently inflated and visible layout in the Activity. if you move the statement outside the method, then Android tries to look for a View in a layout that is currently null, as `setContentView()` is usually called in `onCreate()`. This results in a null value for your EditText, which then causes a `NullPointerException` when you try to call any of the member functions of the EditText.

Answer (score 0):

Write the code declaring the EditText in onCreate() method with a private variable to access it within the class

```
Public Class someclass extends Activity{

   private  editText;
   @override
   protected onCreate(Bundle b){
   editText = findViewById(R.id.edit);
  }
}
```

Use the variable editText anywhere/any function in the class.

Comment: Sorry fr my poor formatting, I'm accessing stackoverflow from Mobile and it is a Pita.

Comment: id rather not create a subclass for something so simple.